# Delphi Web Development - using TWinControl to draw objects

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I want to develop a Web application in Delphi using VCL. I tried UniGUI, but it does not seem to work. Well, it works, but quite not how I wanted. Let me explain.

My problem is that I do want a library whose visual controls expose `Handle` to them. UniGUI does that, but it's not working correctly - for example, the main form has a `Handle` set to `0`, but a `TUniPanel` has a different handle and what's more - it's always the same, even if I run the app in another window or tab.

I want to have a control which exposes its `Handle` correctly, because I need it for the purposes of the application I want to develop.

Do you know any other VCL library which allows me to do that? I tried Intraweb, but it does not seem to solve my problem either.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write an application that runs on a browser using Delphi or you want to write an Internet Browser in Delphi?

Comment: The first one. But I need the GUI of the app to have `Handle` of its visual controls.

Comment: Are you talking about creating an ActiveX application or one that generates HTML?

Comment: No, look at my comment below.

Comment: `TWinControl`s are only for native or ActiveX (native DLL) programs.  Try using different classes (say, use IntraWeb) and generate the HTML.  For those classes, there will be different ways to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do with a `Handle` property.  A Handle is only valid on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know that a web browser could host VCL code would be through an ActiveX.  I wouldn't really advise you to take that approach.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of ActiveX, but as far as I know, it's not supported by browsers other than IE. Have you ever looked at UniGUI? I'm actually looking for a library similar to that one, but one which creates correct `Handle`s for visual controls. Is it possible at all?

Comment: As you surely know, controls like `TPanel` or `TButton` have a `Handle` associated with them and using commands like `SetWindowText()` I can change their captions. UniGUI does associate a `Handle` with its controls (f.i. `TUniPanel`, `TUniButton`), but using the very same command and passing the `Handle` of a UniGUI control does not change the label of the control. That's just an example, what I really wanna use is `SetParent` and thus I need a valid `Handle`.

Comment: Browsers typically render lots of their elements without creating windowed controls. And of course, windowed controls only have meaning on Windows anyway. I stand by the statement I made in the answer.